# Machine Learning. Can Neural Network software model continious phenomena?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

Computer (calculator with extra devices) performs

1. Control flow (compare and jump, goto next instruction)
2. Read write bytes to devices which store them
3. Calculates large boolean functions

**q1. How such hardware can simulate the human brain, which is continuous in nature? Or Is neural network, which will work on pc can approximate any continious not linear phenomena?**

I just wanted to mention, that mathematical experience shows that:

---

1. This things continious and discrete is fundamentally different things. In some cases we can create continious phenomena, for example recreate sound which we can here from samples via Sampling Theorem.

But during proov of this Kolmogorov (or) Shannon (or) Nyquist formula we assume couple things

p1. Signal is bandlimited (we can not here some frequencies with hear)

p2. Signal is also timelimited (we assume it by implictly ignore samples outside time interval)

I don't want to go deeper, but even here it can be prooved that p1 contradict to p2. Even here it is an approximation when you apply this correct theorem "a bit incorrectly".

---

2. We are as people - not able to integrate something, we do it via finite approximation and usually we do it lineary.
   Examples:

ex1. It is impossible to solve this y'=x^3+y^3 analitically.

ex2. It is impossible to find antiderivative of sinc analitically.

### I think we are really far away from create some ai.

**q2: So I think that it is another point of view to finite boolean functions from Discrete Mathematics. Not more over. Am I wrong?**

Comment: Yes they can. It is a non-linear curve fitter. Before the perceptron was discovered and continuous functions like sigmoids were used it was unclear if neural networks could be used for non-continous (for example boolean or sign/step funs) fitting.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it is not clear that the behavior of the brain, as far as thinking is concerned, is continuous in nature. I am no expert on the brain, but my understanding of some of the research is that things such as memories are actually constructed from the brain "interpolating" from finite sets of data.

Second, all the continuous mathematics that has been developed was done by finite constructions on a finite set of symbols. Even without invoking pure formalism, you should understand that while we deal with concepts of smooth and continuous things, what we can prove about them is fundamentally finite. Artificial Intelligence is no more limited than Real Intelligence in this sense.

Comment: Thanks. About second point. We can label with some letter A="0+0+...+0 (infinite time)" or B="summ of geometric series in the limit", (|q|<1) C = "Definition of the Reiman integral..." problem1: We use labels becuase we ca not write this in paper,we will write and write A, and more andmore precise evaluation of B,C...Even after 100 years we will not stop to write. problem2: I don't understand really how machine which I described as personal computer can derive this....

Comment: We not only cannot write $0+0+0+...$ for an infinite number of values, we cannot define the concept of performing addition an infinite number of times. If you look at the definition of an infinite series, you see that it is not defined as an infinite process of summation, but rather it is defined in a completely finite manner: It is the unique $L$ such that for all $\epsilon > 0$, there is an $M$ such that for all $N > M$, $\left|\sum_{n=0}^N a_n - L \right | < \epsilon$. No infinite actions taken there.

Comment: I canimagine that PC can: Derive theorems which are take finite number of steps (no math. induction), finite number of axiom (I guess usually it is si), finite number of elements (no infinite elements)....So I do not believe that personal computer can derive for example something about infinite sets: E.g. Z~(Z\1)

Comment: The personal computer can do it in the same way mathematicians have done it. No mathematician has ever performed an infinite task, and there have been finite numbers of mathematicians. What has been done in mathematics is finite. And therefore within reach, theoretically, of a computer.

Comment: Thanks. I know that "inf. summ" was introduced and formally defined like limit of partial summs. But it seemed to me that I can imagine this one 0+0+...+0 strctly inf. times without usage of limit theory. Even if it leads to fundamental contradictions, I do not understand why we can imagine infinite sets, but we can not imagine apply binary operation infinite times...Something similar is with delta function. If not used limits or tempered distributions then ** I should use "INF" explicitly for function value...I will create separate topic on it.

Comment: I created separate question about it here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1529959/is-infinite-binary-operation-for-zeros-00-0-well-defined-math-object And received a lot of minuses. For somebody it seems stupid question.

Comment: They don't necessarily think the question is stupid, but they truly do not understand what you are asking. This is partly from flaws in your English (though far better than my mastery of any other language), partly because your mathematical knowlege is not sufficient to allow you to state the question well (but if it were, you likely would not have need to ask it at all). Now there are a few here who evince an attitude of "that is stupid, so you shouldn't ask it", but for most, they just don't understand what you mean.